# Passing Parameters into a TestNG XML

Tags: java, xml, maven, parameters, testng

I'm using a combination of Maven with TestNG to run my automation tests and for each test/test set, I currently have a separate TestNG XML file for the same. My issue is when it comes to scalability. How can I reduce the number of TestNG XML files used?

Typically, each test set of mine has like only one class in it. So, I was wondering is there any way I can pass a parameter or something while executing the test call to the TestNG XML to reduce the number of XML files.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I cant club multiple tests and group them in one as each tests are triggered via another framework. These needs to be ran separately upon requirement. Any other solutions/suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Its not clear as to what you are after. You state that you cannot club multiple test classes into the same testng suite xml file and they have to reside as separate. It would be great if you could add some samples in terms of what each of the xmls would look like and what is the sort of optimization you are looking for, to help you scale your test setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround for the same. I created a batch file to accept parameter and based on the input parameters passed to the batch file, it creates the TestNG xml i require on runtime and thereby reducing the number of TestNG Xml.