# How can I send value from Java file to testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I would like to know if we can send value from Java file to testng.xml. This is one of my requirement in current project. As I am completely new to automation testing. Help me how I can achieve it

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: So basically you want to write some data into an XML? Check some XML libraries out there: http://www.baeldung.com/java-xml-libraries

Comment: any code example? what value you want to send?

Comment: I hope it would be testng file to java file. isn't it?

Comment: The answer you seek has being provided in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174161/passing-parameters-into-a-testng-xml

Comment: No, it's from Java to testng config xml file

Comment: I want to send browser name to parameter annotation in xml file